# LINQ: What does All() return if there is no element?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

This is a very simple question but "All" is such a bad keyword to google lol.

I want to get all categories, where none of its products are updated, or don't have any products.

In other words, get all categories, where all of its products are not yet updated, including all categories that don't have any products yet.

Is this the right expression?

```
var categs = context.Categories.Where(c => c.Products.All(x => !x.Updated));
```

Comment: Yep, looks correct.  Protip: you could have googled "linq all", it's the first hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It returns `true`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **Return value**
>   true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, **or if the sequence is empty**; otherwise, false.

(This is the logical conclusion too. *All* of the elements in the sequence do indeed pass the predicate, in the same way that *all* of my daughters are over 10 feet tall. The fact that I don't have any daughters doesn't change the truth of the statement :)

See my [Edulinq blog post on `Any` and `All`](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-10-any-and-all.aspx) for more details about how they work.

Comment: Logically, the text you bolded is redundant. If the sequence is empty, every element of the sequence satisfies the test. But as this question shows, not everyone gets that.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, indeed. I was going to reply saying that it returned true for the *logical* reason, but as the documentation states it explicitly, I figured I'd go with that :)

Comment: Haha, actually it makes sense! I am just having a brain jam for coding all day. Thanks Jon!

Comment: @JonSkeet - Or we could rephrase this and say `Returns false if any element fails the test` - for me that makes the example with your non-existent daughters clearer :-)

Comment: @Joanna: Right - and indeed, `foo.All(p)` is equivalent to `!foo.Any(x => !p(x))`.

Comment: @ShawnFeatherly: Better, I've updated the link to my new blog location.

Answer (score 4):

All "Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition."

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

I think that your expression is correct.You get all the categories which contain products that are not updated.